# How can I hook functions that misuse the stack?

Tags: windows, hook

I have a DLL that gets injected into a process and hooks various functions using a Detours-like hooking library. In my hooks I call the original function with the original parameters and log some data. This all works fine. The problem is that on rare occasions (only two instances thus far) I'll encounter a process that behaves badly. What happens is that in my hook I end up using more stack space than the original function used, and this ends up overwriting data on the stack that the process was relying on. I assume the process is doing something like this:

```
WCHAR* GetSomePath()
{
    // path exists on stack
    WCHAR szSomePath[MAX_PATH];
    // get the path from somewhere
    return szSomePath;
}

int main()
{
    WCHAR* szSomePath = GetSomePath();
    DWORD dwFileAttributes = GetFileAttributesW(szSomePath);
    DeleteFileW(szSomePath);
    return 0;
}
```

So in this example I'll hook `GetFileAttributesW()` and log some data. The problem is that logging the data ends up using more stack space than the original function and ends up overwriting the value of `szSomePath` on the stack, and when `DeleteFileW()` is called it is passed garbage data. This is obviously a contrived example, but it illustrates the general problem. So I'm trying to figure out a way to avoid these types of situations if at all possible.

My first thought was to use a different stack but I'm not quite sure how I'd do that. One option I came across was to [use fibers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200601-00/?p=103815). Unfortunately, the calls to set that up use too much stack space themselves. Is there some kind of low-level stack manipulation I can do to use a different stack in my hook? Not sure where to go from here.